# Django - How to get the language from the URL in a context processor?

Tags: python, django

I would like to display content in a template page according to the language in the URL.

And I have a context processor where I would like to capture the language from the URL. This is my code:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<language>[a-z]{2})$', 'users.views.front_page_language'),
```

**context_processors.py**

```
def categories(request, language):
    return {'categories': category.objects.all(), 'request_language': language}
```

Currently 'request_language' returns 'None'. Is there a way to capture the language portion of the URL?

```
Eg: http://mydomain.com/en/ 'request_language' should return 'en'
```

Thanks in advance

**SOLUTION**

If I pass the language from the view to the template it works. Thanks everyone.

**views.py**

```
def front_page_language(request,language):
    return render_to_response('users/front_page.html', {'request_language': language}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: I don't get any errors, except request_language in my template html is None.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `/` at the end:

```
url(r'^(?P<language>[a-z]{2})/$', 'users.views.front_page_language'),
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing the detail. It helped to track the issue.